# Lost My REMIX IDE code, cleaning browser cache

Tags: remix-tests

I accidentally lost my final year research project code, which was on remix IDE (chrome), while cleaning my browser cache. How can I recover that?

Comment: Apparently files are deleted when you remove the cache, see the docs https://remix-ide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/file_explorer.html#file-storage. Maybe check if the IndexedDB is still saved somewhere in your pc. You can try some disk recovery tool to get the deleted file... good luck!